# SQL Server - How to select the most recent record per user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute a SQL command which should draw on the last row that entered the database.

Basically, when a user submits the last thread (like in this forum), it redirects the user to a page with his thread title, thread paragraph and data such as a user name and time the thread was submitted.

I started working on the statement:

```
SELECT @UserID, u.UsersName, t.ThreadTitle, t.ThreadParagraph
FROM Users as u
INNER JOIN Threads as t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
Where @UserID = t.UserId
```

The problem that I have is that i need to add some statement or aggregate function to return me the last row that was entered in the threads table. How do I do this? what do I need to add?

Comment: If you inserted the data into a table with a indentity column, you can use "SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM YourTable" to get the ID.  Using the ID you can select the row you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MS SQL you can use `TOP 1` for this, you also need to order by your created date time column descending.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @UserID, u.UsersName, t.ThreadTitle, t.ThreadParagraph
FROM Users as u
    INNER JOIN Threads as t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
Where @UserID=t.UserId
ORDER BY [YourDateTimeFiled] DESC
```

Comment: so top 1 would give me the last thread inserted..what if two users insert a thread near the same time... my field is datetime.. how accurate is it?

Comment: Matrix001 - `ORDER BY` will order so the column with the largest datetime will be first. `TOP 1` will make sure that all other rows are ignored. Also, from my understanding it does not matter what other users do as you filter by concrete user `@UserID=t.UserId`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have exactly understood your question, but if you have a thread id (primary key in your threads table), try this

```
SELECT @UserID, u.UsersName, t.ThreadTitle, t.ThreadParagraph
FROM Users as u
INNER JOIN Threads as t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
Where @UserID=t.UserId
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have LIMIT

Comment: @gbn He did not mention Sql Server in his first question ;)